# How to use getClass().getResource() method

Tags: java

**When I create ImageIcon class objects I use the following code:**

```
iconX = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("imageX.png"))
```

---

The above code works correctly either in an applet or a desktop app when the .png is in the same folder of the class.

The question is: how to avoid a `NullPointerException` when the .Png is in another folder? Or how load the image in the object `ImageIcon` when it is in a different location to the class?

I don't understand how this method works, if anyone can help me I appreciate it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this - [`Class#getResource(java.lang.String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)

Please click the link above and read the docs and follow to understand what's going on.

It says -

> If the name begins with a '/', then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.

and

> Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
>
> ```
>      modified_package_name/name
> ```
>
> Where the modified_package_name is the package name of **this object** with '/' substituted for '.'.

So, if **this object** (where you call `getResource`) is in package `/pkg1` (`/` meaning pkg1 is right under the root of the classpath) and you used "imageX.png" then the result would be `pkg1/imageX.png` which is correct because that's where the image is located at.

But, if we moved the resource (imageX.png) to some other package `/pkg2` and you called the method same way then the result would still be `pkg1/imageX.png` but this time it would be incorrect because the resource is actually located in `/pkg2`. That's when you end up with NPE.

It's good to explicitly specify the full path of the resource starting from the root of the classpath. (e.g. "/pkg/imageX.png").

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Simply supply the path to the resource.

So, if you put the image in "/resources/images" within your Jar, you would simply use

```
iconX = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/images/imageX.png"))
```

Essentially what you're saying is, class loader, please search your class path for the following resource.

Answer (score 1):

If the image is internal (you want a location relative to your project, or perhaps packaged into your jar), do what mad programmer said:

```
iconX = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/path/imageX.png"))
```

The path is relative, so path/ will be a folder in the same folder as your project (or packaged into your jar).

If you want an external image, simply hand ImageIcon constructor the path (ex. "C:/.../file.png"). This isn't recommended though, as it's better to use it as a resource.

For more info on the ImageIcon constructor, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html). for more info on loading class resources, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E18745_01/apidocs/oracle/adf/view/faces/resource/ResourceLoader.html) (Javadoc links)

Comment: Ok You're right about the resource folder, is better that way. I tried the full path of the file in a different folder to the classpath and get an nullPointerExceptioin too. I using de following code: imageX = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("C:/Users/JP/Desktop/applet/iconX.png")); and doesn't work!