# Image cannot show on Jbutton

Tags: java, swing

I dunno where I have gone wrong, I have tried all possible ways to get the image to display on the JButton, but cannot figure out why the getResource class brings a null pointer.
I have also checked the path i used again and again, but the path i provided is correct.

please help

```
public class Media extends JPanel {

//Declares our media player component
private JPanel video_pnl;
private JButton play_btn;
private JLabel loc_lbl;
private int increment;
ArrayList<String> file_location;

public Media(ArrayList<String> file_location) {
    this.file_location = file_location;
    increment = 0;
    while (increment < file_location.size()) {

        video_pnl = new JPanel();
        video_pnl.setLayout(new BoxLayout(video_pnl, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        loc_lbl = new JLabel();
        loc_lbl.setText(file_location.get(increment));

        play_btn = new JButton("Play");
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("a.png"));
        play_btn.setIcon(img);

        video_pnl.add(loc_lbl);
        video_pnl.add(play_btn);
        add(video_pnl);
        increment++;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Declare and initialize local variables
    ArrayList<String> file_location = new ArrayList<>();
    file_location.add("A");
    file_location.add("B");

    //creates instances of the VlcPlayer object, pass the mediaPath and invokes the method "run"
    Media mediaplayer = new Media(file_location);
    JFrame ourframe = new JFrame();
    ourframe.setContentPane(mediaplayer);
    ourframe.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
    ourframe.setSize(300, 560);
    ourframe.setVisible(true);
    ourframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

Comment: Could you show us your directory structure?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103371/how-to-use-getclass-getresource-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Tested your code and it works fine. Your image is most likely in the wrong location.

If you're going to use *just* the image file name as the path i.e. `"a.png"`, then the image needs to be in the same package as your class that's calling it. For example

```
ProjectRoot
         src
            some.package
                      Media.java
                      a.png
```

Upon build, the image will get copied the the class path, being in the same package as `Media.class`

Answer (score 0):

```
file_location.add("A");
file_location.add("B");
```

You need to specify the path to your file. All you are doing is adding two alphabets and hence the `NullPointerException` when you try to get the resource as a steam. If the name of your images are indeed `A` and `B` then specify the extension.