# GUI code doesn't run - from Deitel book

Tags: java, swing

I have created a project named "LabelTest" under JavaWorkspace in JCreator Pro version 5.10

In project folder I have added files LabelFrame.java, LabelTest.java and an icon bug1.png from Deitel "java how to program" 8th edition chapter 14 figures 6 and 7

Project builds succesfuly but doesn't run. 
Here are the errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
    at labeltest.LabelFrame.<init>(LabelFrame.java:30)
    at labeltest.LabelTest.main(LabelTest.java:11)
```

and the code:

```
// Fig. 14.6: LabelFrame.java
// Demonstrating the JLabel class.
//package labeltest;

import java.awt.FlowLayout; // specifies how components are arranged
import javax.swing.JFrame; // provides basic window features
import javax.swing.JLabel; // displays text and images
import javax.swing.SwingConstants; // common constants used with Swing
import javax.swing.Icon; // interface used to manipulate images
import javax.swing.ImageIcon; // loads images

public class LabelFrame extends JFrame 
{
   private JLabel label1; // JLabel with just text
   private JLabel label2; // JLabel constructed with text and icon
   private JLabel label3; // JLabel with added text and icon

   // LabelFrame constructor adds JLabels to JFrame
   public LabelFrame()
   {
      super( "Testing JLabel" );
      setLayout( new FlowLayout() ); // set frame layout

      // JLabel constructor with a string argument
      label1 = new JLabel( "Label with text" );
      label1.setToolTipText( "This is label1" );
      add( label1 ); // add label1 to JFrame

      // JLabel constructor with string, Icon and alignment arguments
      Icon bug = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource( "bug1.png" ) );
      label2 = new JLabel( "Label with text and icon", bug, 
         SwingConstants.LEFT );
      label2.setToolTipText( "This is label2" );
      add( label2 ); // add label2 to JFrame

      label3 = new JLabel(); // JLabel constructor no arguments
      label3.setText( "Label with icon and text at bottom" );
      label3.setIcon( bug ); // add icon to JLabel
      label3.setHorizontalTextPosition( SwingConstants.CENTER );
      label3.setVerticalTextPosition( SwingConstants.BOTTOM );
      label3.setToolTipText( "This is label3" );
      add( label3 ); // add label3 to JFrame
   } // end LabelFrame constructor
} // end class LabelFrame


// Fig. 14.7: LabelTest.java
// Testing LabelFrame.
//package labeltest;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class LabelTest 
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   { 
      LabelFrame labelFrame = new LabelFrame(); // create LabelFrame
      labelFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      labelFrame.setSize( 260, 180 ); // set frame size
      labelFrame.setVisible( true ); // display frame
   } // end main
} // end class LabelTest
```

Comment: Is `bug1.png` a file on your classpath? I doubt. Look in the debugger for the value of `getClass().getResource( "bug1.png" )`, log it or output it with `System.out.println()`.

Comment: Take a look into this question : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103371/how-to-use-getclass-getresource-method

Answer (score 0):

Your program can be compiled by unable to run is because it hits an exception at this line:

```
Icon bug = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource( "bug1.png" ) );
```

The exception is a result of not being able to locate a file named `bug1.png`.

Ensure you use the correct ***pathname*** and ***filename***.

Comment: Additionally, the program is incorrect because it is creating Swing components on the main thread, it needs to do that on the EDT thread. Some environments (e.g. Windows) you can get away with this, other environments (e.g. OS X) are much more strict.