# getClass().getResource method not working

Tags: java, image, netbeans-8

I have been trying to run this code so that images from the specified folder are able to be viewed, but i keep getting a whole list of errors and i do not know how to fix them.

> ERRORS:Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   fatface.FatFace.getImages(FatFace.java:27)

[Problem is shown on this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzSHG.png)

Comment: don't post images or external links, copy the code here. [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

try using

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("fatface/pictures").getFile()
```

Example

```
File f = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().
             getResource("fatface/pictures/").getFile());  

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(f.list()));
```

Output:
[temp.jpg]

Comment: Why should they try this?

Comment: because the getClass().getResource() method returns the resource if the resource is in same package else it returns null. see this post 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103371/how-to-use-getclass-getresource-method

therefore the correct way to load resource is ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource()

Comment: All of that belongs in your answer.